# C++ Tic-Tac-Toe using classes

Tags: c++, class, tic-tac-toe

The game displays the matrix, but doesn't update the current move.
How can I do that?

Here I will show the code I have until now.
I define a matrix for the board.
The functions will draw the board, will get the move from the player, and will toggle the turns.

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H
#define TICTACTOE_H

class TicTacToe
{
private:
    char board[3][3];

public:
    void DrawBoard();
    void PrintBoard();
    void GetMove(int move);
    void TogglePlayer(char player);
    bool DetermineDraw();
};

#endif
```

Here is the implementation file:
My function to draw the board displays the matrix, but doesn't update the moves.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToe.h"

using namespace std;


void TicTacToe::DrawBoard()
{
    system("cls");
    cout <<"\tWelcome to the Classes Tic Tac Toe! \n";
    char board[3][3] =
    { 
      {'1','2','3'},
      {'4','5','6'},
      {'7','8','9'},
    };

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void TicTacToe::GetMove(int move)
{
    char player = 'X';
    cout <<"\nEnter the number of the field you would like to move:\n";
    cin >> move;

    if( move == 1)
    {
        board[0][0] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 2)
    {
        board[0][1] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 3)
    {
        board[0][2] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 4)
    {
        board[1][0] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 5)
    {
        board[1][1] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 6)
    {
        board[1][2] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 7)
    {
        board[2][0] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 8)
    {
        board[2][1] = player;
    }
    else if(move == 9)
    {
        board[2][2] = player;
    }

}

void TicTacToe::TogglePlayer(char player)
{
    if (player == 'X')
        player = 'O';
    else if(player == 'O')
        player = 'X';
}

bool TicTacToe::DetermineDraw()
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == 'X' && board[i][j] == 'O')
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main file, I will keep looping through the game while it isn't a draw.
I don't know why the move isn't shown on the board.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToe.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TicTacToe game;
    char player = 'X';
    while(game.DetermineDraw() == false)
    {
        game.DrawBoard();
        game.GetMove(player);
        game.TogglePlayer(player);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?

Comment: `board[move/3][move%3] = player`: remove your `if` statements.

Comment: Your `TogglePlayer` function changes the **copy** of the `player` parameter, then exits.  The original `player` variable is not changed.  Did you mean to pass by reference? Or were you planning on have a `player` variable in your `TicTacToe` class.

Comment: You are passing the player symbol to your `GetMove` function, but the function is expecting a board square number.

Comment: Your `GetMove` method always places the player `X` and never `O`.

Comment: Yep, a debugger would help you immensely find these issues.  Using paper and pencil, drawing a table for the variables and executing each statement would help too.

Comment: Your `DetermineDraw` method never makes more than one iteration, because both clauses of the `if` statement return.  Another issue that using a debugger can find.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but still I don't know how to update the board.

Comment: In your `DetermineDraw` method, how can the expression `(board[i][j] == 'X') && (board[i][j] == 'O')` ever be true?  The slot in the board can *never* equal both values.  Perhaps you meant to use `||`?  **Using a debugger would help you catch this one.**  *Are you getting the hint yet?*  If you don't know how to use the debugger, learn.

Comment: Yes I know how to use the debugger, and yes, i should have used ||

Answer (score 1):

`TicTacToe::DrawBoard()` always draw the same board, because it uses locally defined variable `board`. To correct: remove local definition and initialize class variable `board` in the constructor:

```
TicTacToe::TicTacToe()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
         board[i / 3][i % 3] = '1' + i;
}

void TicTacToe::DrawBoard()
{
    system("cls");
    cout <<"\tWelcome to the Classes Tic Tac Toe! \n";

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch!  I would have eventually found this one.